Spring boot soap webservice interceptor
how to create a soap interceptor in spring boot soap webservice and log the soap request headers and soap body before calling the soap endpoint method
I am excepting the sample code for interceptor and where to configure the interceptor in order to work with spring boot soap

You don't need an interceptor for that. Spring WebServices has a special logger for that which  yo only need to enable.

please let me know how to enable it
